# Java Swing move JFrame with mouse

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, mouseevent

Im playing around with Java swing graphics etc. Im atm trying to design a register/login form.

[image]

I have setUndecorated(true), and have created my own top bar. When you drag that bar I want the entire frame to move. And I also want the mouse to stay in the same position on the frame.

With this code applied:

The frame is moving. But the mouse moves to the top right corner, the frames initial X and Y coordinates.

```
    JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);

    int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; // Mouse X Coordinate
    int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y; // Mouse Y Coordinate
    int diffX = mouseX - frame.getX(); // The distance from JFrame X Coordinate to Mouse X Coordinate. 
    int diffY = mouseY - frame.getY(); // The distance from JFrame Y Coordinate to Mouse Y Coordinate.



    if (diffY < 45) { // Y Coordinate 0 - 45 is the height of the top part of the window. Where you can move the frame.
        frame.setLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
```

[image]

This code below should to my knowledge make the mouse stay in its position before dragging.

```
    JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);

    int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; // Mouse X Coordinate
    int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y; // Mouse Y Coordinate
    int diffX = mouseX - frame.getX(); // The distance from JFrame X Coordinate to Mouse X Coordinate. 
    int diffY = mouseY - frame.getY(); // The distance from JFrame Y Coordinate to Mouse Y Coordinate.



    if (diffY > 0 && diffY < 45) { // Y Coordinate 0 - 45 is the height of the top part of the window. Where you can move the frame.
        int x = mouseX - diffX;
        int y = mouseY - diffY;

        frame.setLocation(x, y);
    }
```

But instead.. nothing happens. The function is called, but the frame is not moving. What am I doing wrong? I cant seem to find the problem.

EDIT* 
I created the ComponentMover class, and created an instance of it like this:

```
    DragListener drag = new DragListener();
    JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);

    int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; // Mouse X Coordinate
    int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y; // Mouse Y Coordinate
    int diffX = mouseX - frame.getX(); // The distance from JFrame X Coordinate to Mouse X Coordinate. 
    int diffY = mouseY - frame.getY(); // The distance from JFrame Y Coordinate to Mouse Y Coordinate.



    if (diffY > 0 && diffY < 45) { // Y Coordinate 0 - 45 is the height of the top part of the window. Where you can move the frame.
        frame.addMouseListener( drag );
        frame.addMouseMotionListener( drag );
    }

    ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover(this, frame);
```

But the problem persists.

Thanks in advance for all help!

EDIT 2*
This is the approach I took to get to ComponentMover to work. Though I'm not sure it can do what I want it to do.

**THIS IS THE CODE**

```
public class CompMoverTest extends JFrame{

    public CompMoverTest(){
        MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setUndecorated(true);
        add(mp);
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CompMoverTest();
    }

}

class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    public MainPanel(){
        JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        setBackground(Color.yellow);

        ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover(frame, this);
    }
}
```

**THIS IS THE RESULT**

[image]

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT**

[image]

I hope this is clear enough. What I have now, is a yellow panel that moves when I drag it. I understand that this is the function of the ComponentMover class.

However, what I want to happen is that when I drag the yellow panel the entire frame moves around the screen like the second gif. Is this possible with the ComponentMover class or no? I cannot get this to work. The rest is fine.

Comment: You can check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a class that will do this for you. You can use the fancy class, or maybe modify the basic dragging code. to add in the simple check to see if the mouse if in the top 45 pixels of the frame.

Comment: Tried implementing that Class. But the same problem persists, nothing happens when I drag it.

Comment: `Tried implementing that Class.` - what class? The ComponentMover class does exactly what you want. The DragListener needs customization and I don't see your [mcve] demonstrating what you did.

Comment: Edited my initial post how i added the class.

Comment: You either use the ComponentMover class or you use the DragListener class, but not both. If you use the ComponentMover class no other code is needed. If you use the DragListener class the custom logic needs to be added to the class. In the mousePressed class you could check is the mouse point is in the bounds of the title bar panel and set a variable. The mouse drag when then only move the frame if the variable is true. The mouseReleased would reset the variable.

Comment: I can't compile or execute the code you posted. What you need is a simple frame with a panel (the rest of your application is irrelevant to the problem). Then you add the ComponentMOver to the panel. Get this working first. If it doesn't work, then you have complete code to poste in the forum so I can see exactly what you are doing. Otherwise, once you understand how to use the class you add it to your real application.

Comment: So.. I created a JFrame with a JPanel inside of it. Im able to move the 
JPanel inside of the JFrame by dragging it. But what I want, is moving the JFrame around on the screen, by dragging the JPanel. This might not be possible, and I'll have to rethink.

Comment: I have no idea which approach you are referring to. Again, the ComponentMover is designed to do this with a single line of code. The link shows you how to do this. I'm not understanding your confusion. I also said if you want to use the DragListener you need to modify the code. You refuse to post a proper [mcve] clarifying what you are doing and I don't have time to keep guessing, so this is the last time I comment without a proper "MCVE".

Comment: I've made a last edit trying my best to explain what I'm getting and what I'm after. If this isn't clear enough there's not much I can do. Thank you for all the help anyways.  EDIT** When I created a JPanel inside of the Main class, instead of creating an external class extending JPanel, it worked. Can't understand why it doesnt work with an external JPanel class though.

Comment: So, I was supposed to create the ComponentMover instance inside of the JFrame class and not the JPanel. Now I got the titlebar to work properly. Thanks for the help you've given me, and sorry for all the confusing struggle.

Comment: The ComponentMover needs access to the JFrame as was demonstrated in the link. I could not guess that you were trying to access the frame in the constructor which won't work because the panel has not yet been added to the frame. This is why we need an [mcve] for every question so we can see exactly what your are doing. See answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
```

The panel hasn't been added to the frame yet, so you can't use the above method in the constructor to access the parent frame.

If you really want to add the ComponentMover in the custom panel class then you can override the addNotify() method:

```
@Override
public void addNotify()
{
    super.addNotify();

    JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
    ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover(frame, this);
}
```